# Electronic component datasheet handling

Tags: power-electronics, rf-electronics, consumer-electronics, microelectronics

What is $V_{IH}$ and $V_{IL}$ in datasheets? I found High-level input voltage and Low-level input voltage on the datasheet?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. In the attached document shows minimum 2.0V and above is considered Logic High. Likewise maximum voltage of 0.8V and below is considered logic low.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

They are the extremes of the voltage at the input which define the required 0 and 1 logic levels. On the data sheet Logic 1 must be at least 2.0v and logic 0 less than 0.8 to function properly.

Comment: It might be better to say "2.0 V is the minimum voltage guaranteed to be read as logic 1 and 0.8 is the maximum voltage guaranteed to be read as logic 0. In-between these levels is undefined." But you've got the right idea. Welcome to E.SE.